# Getting error Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key while reading file from ADLS Gen2 using service principal

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am getting error while reading file from ADLS Gen2 using service principal.

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": 
           "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<your-service-client-id>",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope 
           = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>"),
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": 
           "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your-directory-id>/oauth2/token"}
```

Below code using to read file:

```
df=spark.read.csv('abfss:
//tempfile@tempaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/temp.csv')
```

Getting below error:

> Invalid configuration value detected for fs.azure.account.key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following:

**Instead of the this line:**

`"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name>")`,

**Try to use as below:**

```
"fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": "<key-name>",
```

Hope this helps.

---

If this answers your query, do click “Mark as Answer” and "Up-Vote" for the same. And, if you have any further query do let us know.

Comment: If you have the key with you then you can use @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT answer

Comment: Hello @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT I`m having the same issue but I don´t understand how to pass the <scope-name> value. Can you pls put the correct way? Thank you in advance my friend

Answer (score 0):

After defining the configs, you need to set it as well.

```
[spark.conf.set(key, value) for (key, value) in configs.items()]
```